# Перенаправления страницы после удаления из бд

Tags: php, mysql

У меня если таблица в котором есть имя *уникальный id* вес динозавра(`weight`) и рост(`height`) соответсвенно и рядом с ними есть  кнопка удаления (`delete`) при нажатии в котором данные будут удалятсья из **db**.

У меня вопрос после удаления `id` из **db** страница перенаправляетсья на  другую страницу я написал js код который вернет user-а обратно в эту страницу но что то не работает.

Данные добавляютсья в **db** с помощью формы

Помогите пожалуйста

файл **delete.php**

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
$db_connect = mysqli_select_db($connection,"new");


$delete_record = $_GET["delete"];

$delete_query = "DELETE FROM dinosaurs WHERE Id = `$delete_record`";


$execute = mysqli_query($connection,$delete_query);

if($execute){
   echo '<script>window.open("view_from_db.php?Deleted=recored deleted succesfully","_self")</script>';
}
```

Также файл **view_from_db.php**

```
<?php 
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root",""); //подключаемсья то датабейс
        $selection = mysqli_select_db($connection,"new"); //выбираем базу фром датабейс
        $view_query = "SELECT * From dinosaurs"; //взять все елементы из database
        $execute = mysqli_query($connection,$view_query); //Выполняет запрос к базе данных

        while ($data_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($execute)) { //Выбирает одну строку из результирующего набора и помещает ее в ассоциативный массив, обычный массив или в оба
           $id = $data_rows["Id"];
           $dinosaur_name = $data_rows["dinosaur_name"];
           $height = $data_rows["height"];
           $weight = $data_rows["weight"];
           $img = $data_rows["Img"];


    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $dinosaur_name; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $height; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $weight; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $img; ?></td>   
        <td><a href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
        <td>edit</td> 
    </tr>    
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ был очень простым мне надо было просто поставить нормальные скобки чтобы все сработало.

Вот тут

```
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM dinosaurs WHERE Id = `$delete_record`";
```

я изменил эти скобки `` на такие '' и все сработало.

```
 $delete_query = "DELETE FROM dinosaurs WHERE Id = '$delete_record'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо

```
if($execute){
   echo '<script>window.open("view_from_db.php?Deleted=recored deleted succesfully","_self")</script>';
}
```

Напишите

```
location($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

А ещё можно ajax'ом открывать урл

На примере JQ меняем строку:

```
 <td><a href="javascript:;" data-href="delete.php?delete=<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a></td>
```

И добавляем скрипт

```
$('[data-href]').on('click', function(){
    url = $(this).data('href');
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(){location.reload();}
    });
});
```

Comment: спасибо конечно что ответили но у меня вопрос.мне полностью заменить if условие и вместо него добавить ваш код или как ?если да то там ошибка выводитсья.=(

Comment: Если вам надо что бы была обработка если выполнено условие или нет то сделайте `location($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` в условии если нет можете поменять

Comment: `location($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` вернёт на страницу с которой пришёл пользователь

Comment: спасибо вам конечно за ответ и я  дам плюсик(чтобы такие как вы всегда отвечали и помогали людям)   но на самом деле решение было очень даже простым.